# Rearrange results from database into array of array for duplicate rows

Tags: javascript, php

I need help rearraning results from database  into array of array for duplicate rows, this is an example of what i get , like 2 results , i have alot of results and need it to group by rota,clientes and artigos. i need to do this in api using php.

```
"dados": [
    {
        "idEncomenda": "1",
        "codigoEncomenda": "06904",
        "codigoArtigo": "601056",
        "numExpedicao": "ZG0054",
        "motorista": "Ricardo Fonseca",
        "cliente": "Muralhas Festival",
        "numCliente": "0067",
        "morada": "Rua 13 de Abril",
        "viatura": "Ferrari",
        "matricula": "22-MM-45",
        "rota": "Rota 01",
        "zonaEntrega": "Aveiro Sul",
        "dataExpedicao": "04-07-2021",
        "observacoes": "Teste asasd agsgjsfsfd",
        "artigo": "Sardinha Pequena EI",
        "qtPalete": "0",
        "caixa": "94",
        "qtExpedida": "0",
        "total": "120",
        "unidade": "KG",
        "qtPicada": "0",
        "lote": "B211215I",
        "dataValidadeArtigo": "16-01-2023",
        "id": "1"
    },
    {
        "idEncomenda": "2",
        "codigoEncomenda": "06904",
        "codigoArtigo": "601034",
        "numExpedicao": "ZG0054",
        "motorista": "Ricardo Fonseca",
        "cliente": "Muralhas Festival",
        "numCliente": "0067",
        "morada": "Rua 13 de Abril",
        "viatura": "Ferrari",
        "matricula": "22-MM-45",
        "rota": "Rota 01",
        "zonaEntrega": "Aveiro Sul",
        "dataExpedicao": "04-07-2021",
        "observacoes": "1233123123",
        "artigo": "Solha",
        "qtPalete": "0",
        "caixa": "100",
        "qtExpedida": "0",
        "total": "100",
        "unidade": "KG",
        "qtPicada": "0",
        "lote": "B213215I",
        "dataValidadeArtigo": "16-01-2023",
        "id": "2"
    },
    {
        "idEncomenda": "3",
        "codigoEncomenda": "06904",
        "codigoArtigo": "606756",
        "numExpedicao": "ZG0054",
        "motorista": "Ricardo Fonseca",
        "cliente": "Muralhas Festival",
        "numCliente": "0067",
        "morada": "Rua 13 de Abril",
        "viatura": "Ferrari",
        "matricula": "22-MM-45",
        "rota": "Rota 01",
        "zonaEntrega": "Aveiro Sul",
        "dataExpedicao": "04-07-2021",
        "observacoes": "1233123123",
        "artigo": "Bacalhau",
        "qtPalete": "0",
        "caixa": "54",
        "qtExpedida": "0",
        "total": "200",
        "unidade": "KG",
        "qtPicada": "0",
        "lote": "B221215I",
        "dataValidadeArtigo": "16-01-2023",
        "id": "3"
    },
    {
        "idEncomenda": "4",
        "codigoEncomenda": "09446",
        "codigoArtigo": "606756",
        "numExpedicao": "ZG0054",
        "motorista": "Ricardo Fonseca",
        "cliente": "Viveiros do Sado",
        "numCliente": "0058",
        "morada": "Rua 23 Marques",
        "viatura": "Ferrari",
        "matricula": "22-MM-45",
        "rota": "Rota 01",
        "zonaEntrega": "Aveiro Sul",
        "dataExpedicao": "04-07-2021",
        "observacoes": "1233123123",
        "artigo": "Bacalhau",
        "qtPalete": "0",
        "caixa": "200",
        "qtExpedida": "0",
        "total": "100",
        "unidade": "KG",
        "qtPicada": "0",
        "lote": "B221215I",
        "dataValidadeArtigo": "16-01-2023",
        "id": "4"
    },
    {
        "idEncomenda": "5",
        "codigoEncomenda": "09446",
        "codigoArtigo": "601034",
        "numExpedicao": "ZG0054",
        "motorista": "Ricardo Fonseca",
        "cliente": "Viveiros do Sado",
        "numCliente": "0058",
        "morada": "Rua 23 Marques",
        "viatura": "Ferrari",
        "matricula": "22-MM-45",
        "rota": "Rota 01",
        "zonaEntrega": "Aveiro Sul",
        "dataExpedicao": "04-07-2021",
        "observacoes": "1233123123",
        "artigo": "Solha",
        "qtPalete": "0",
        "caixa": "200",
        "qtExpedida": "0",
        "total": "140",
        "unidade": "KG",
        "qtPicada": "0",
        "lote": "B213215I",
        "dataValidadeArtigo": "16-01-2023",
        "id": "5"
    },
```

]

and i need it to check when rota is the same ,i need to group by cliente(client) like each rota can have multiple clients and each client can have multiple artigos(items),i show and example of 2 items but i have a list of 300 items.

This is an example of what i want :

```
"dados": [
    {
        "idEncomenda": "1",
        "numExpedicao": "ZG0054",
        "motorista": "Ricardo Fonseca",
        "numCliente": "0067",
        "viatura": "Ferrari",
        "matricula": "22-MM-45",
        "rota": "Rota 01",
        "zonaEntrega": "Aveiro Sul",
        "dataExpedicao": "04-07-2021",
        "observacoes": "Teste asasd agsgjsfsfd",
        "id": "1",
        "clientes": [
            {
                "cliente": "Muralhas Festival",
                "numCliente": "0067",
                "morada": "Rua 13 de Abril",
                "codigoEncomenda": "06904",
                "artigos": [
                    {
                        "artigo": "Sardinha Pequena EI",
                        "qtPalete": "0",
                        "caixa": "94",
                        "qtExpedida": "0",
                        "total": "120",
                        "unidade": "KG",
                        "qtPicada": "0",
                        "lote": "B211215I",
                        "dataValidadeArtigo": "16-01-2023",
                        "codigoArtigo": "601056"
                    },
                    {
                        "artigo": "Solha",
                        "qtPalete": "0",
                        "caixa": "100",
                        "qtExpedida": "0",
                        "total": "100",
                        "unidade": "KG",
                        "qtPicada": "0",
                        "lote": "B213215I",
                        "dataValidadeArtigo": "16-01-2023",
                    },
                    {
                        "artigo": "Bacalhau",
                        "qtPalete": "0",
                        "caixa": "54",
                        "qtExpedida": "0",
                        "total": "200",
                        "unidade": "KG",
                        "qtPicada": "0",
                        "lote": "B221215I",
                        "dataValidadeArtigo": "16-01-2023",
                    }
                ]
                "cliente": "Viveiros Monte Real",
                "numCliente": "0067",
                "morada": "Rua 13 de Abril",
                "codigoEncomenda": "06904",
                "artigos": [
                    {
                        "artigo": "Bacalhau",
                        "qtPalete": "0",
                        "caixa": "200",
                        "qtExpedida": "0",
                        "total": "100",
                        "unidade": "KG",
                        "qtPicada": "0",
                        "lote": "B221215I",
                        "dataValidadeArtigo": "16-01-2023",
                    },
                    {
                        "artigo": "Solha",
                        "qtPalete": "0",
                        "caixa": "200",
                        "qtExpedida": "0",
                        "total": "140",
                        "unidade": "KG",
                        "qtPicada": "0",
                        "lote": "B213215I",
                        "dataValidadeArtigo": "16-01-2023",
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
```

Here is what i came up with so far:

```
public static function getExpedicao()
{
    $expedicoes = self::find()->asArray()->all();

    foreach ($expedicoes as $key => $value) {
        $expedicoes[$key]["id"] = $value["idEncomenda"];
    }

    foreach ($expedicoes as $key => $value) {
        $expedicoes[$key]['artigos'] = [array_splice($value, 14, 9)+ array_splice($value, 2, 1)];
    }

    foreach ($expedicoes as &$item) {
        unset($item['artigo'], $item['qtPalete'], $item['caixa'], $item['qtExpedida'], $item['total'], $item['unidade'], $item['qtPicada'], $item['lote'], $item['dataValidadeArtigo'],$item['codigoArtigo']);
    }

    foreach ($expedicoes as $key => $value) {
        $expedicoes[$key]["clientes"] = [array_splice($value, 4, 3) + array_splice($value, 1, 1) + array_splice($value, 10, 12)];
    }

    foreach ($expedicoes as &$item) {
        unset($item['cliente'], $item['num_cliente'], $item['morada'], $item['codigoEncomenda'], $item['artigos']);
    }

    $res = array();

    foreach ($expedicoes as $values) {

        if (!isset($res[$values['rota']])) {
            $res[$values['rota']] = $values;
        }


    }

    $res = array_values($res);
    return [
        "resposta" => true,
        "dados" => $res,
    ];
}
```

Comment: I think these have the wrong tags :)

Comment: sorry just changed it

Comment: The input data you have shown, does not seem to match the desired result. Please show a _proper_ example, with the two actually matching.

Comment: @Arti Please show proper input array and desired output array which has match logically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still your example input confusing with expected output but here is my answer as I understand.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7VRdb9owFH3nV1whNFpprEn4qCpKJzZBVU1IFUx9GEKVmxjwFuLUdhDd2t/O7CRODC0t2njYpOQpuuf6@txzz3U4D9fr84/hPCyVKogx9DCeQAfGJZBfmVGBytC5gPJQ/oFll98ngOsTHAicYIOIIX@OOPQxF2SJfJ0VRIveKsQecRFNUr9dWlazoXHEBJmlyAgxjwRzBNf4PsIBgt5VV@cRrxe4dIEDL2WT86CerLCFWq0zq7GZ0TVualm21WxpfEEFZYRnfUquzKPQpwHHLjI6@Wy2bFmt07wCQ/rqYYTAroOHoXvHSCbEkiAhRUpy@ljKzEh2HAlG3MhPUcepDQa1RlPDP2mAeoFgeJYmdJeYMAqjKKvuIYG2dLYaNeu05lhOphS945gtkUsxT1K@ymFhQBxxD9CMz77zKZ96Ov1eXCMfZ@1maiKySnmcNfLc5PZMfw0IaRo/nZiTRaNAZnpp5S@Xxo2S/7MaPtUkPjm27djNK7PtG@THxcz52q2aZave67l/tG1Kk/af@/yGxNJzGFAZgyF@y@l1Z0@nF0YvjH5Iozv/qtFHhdMLpx/S6fV9ne686vQ37F1/zd6FpQtLH9LSjcNYev/H@1V3j4onu/D3Qf3d3Nff9cLfhb//P3@3En@fnEBXjiCYYVA1gAScyInhlWAIlnI06M7HH0oVGokwEmoL4q1IvN4n2Pd4vhp6A54bZdMeOwyrF07R3y6dLsX2RDZG8XwEG9pvSb4ttanxblVf2qSY95QyjNw5HCUvhjQTVEjg4ZVSu6IqHcOv@HCeGSuuEn/ghzhtifwI6zz1kalMi9EOVFN5q/D4CFkwEaZqHlKfK58dEkS4nUWfStlvOs1xTGBcVS9adTIZq5rqoUtoJCfTUznnjckr7kbAJLHjDt0Er040pNtSDIxiE1mkkyi3Gd9BbMM3ipgR@GtiqcwxaNSd5AzNqGb4FO/XEC/oEoO6CKaMLiDdpcQnUnNzveLgbTwAfpSGj9tmnZTVrlK5IBrj8E79aw3Uv9ntS5eauLxd9oHdOYXyecjwRbkdMhKIW5bzS9GTBMYrItql9fo3)

```
// Arrange data inside extra variable.
$output = [];

$clientFields = [
    "cliente",
    "numCliente",
    "morada",
    "codigoEncomenda"
];

$artigoFields = [
    "artigo",
    "qtPalete",
    "caixa",
    "qtExpedida",
    "total",
    "unidade",
    "qtPicada",
    "lote",
    "dataValidadeArtigo",
    "codigoArtigo"
];

foreach ($array as $index => $data) {
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if ($key == 'cliente' || $key == 'artigo') {
            continue;
        }

        $output[$data['rota']][$key] = $value;
    }

    foreach ($clientFields as $clientField) {
        $output[$data['rota']]['clientes'][$data['cliente']][$clientField]   = $data[$clientField];
    }

    foreach ($artigoFields as $artigoField) {
        $output[$data['rota']]['clientes'][$data['cliente']]['artigos'][$artigoField] = $data[$artigoField];
    }
}

// Remove rota from output array key.
$output = array_values($output);

// Remove cliente from output array key.
foreach ($output as &$out) {
    $out['clientes'] = array_values($out['clientes']);
}

echo "<pre>";print_r($output);echo "</pre>";exit;
```

Check it and let me know if any issue.

Comment: what if "cliente" is different and "artigos" is different and i want to do array with different "clientes" and each "cliente" has different "artigos"

Comment: Okay so we've to put artigos inside client.

Comment: and adding to it clients cant be repeated , like if they are the same u add "artigos" to the one that was the same, imagine client is 3 times repeated it needs to have 3 "artigos" inside him

Comment: Please give me example input array and expected output array which contains all of possibilities.

Comment: I updated what i get and what i want in top post , but theres a thing that everytime " rota" is different it will make another group , so imagine i have 3 different "rotas" , its 3 objects with all those sub arrays.idk u get me

Comment: In your expected output, there is clientes array inside it duplicate cliente key. And I think you know array key must be unique.

Comment: Ignore the client duplicate ,think of them as different , i dont have different data atm sorry!

Comment: @Arti Please check my updated answer.

Comment: very close  of what i need now only thing left is idk if you see my edited answer i need the other values in each client and each Artigo

Comment: @Arti Check my updated answer with your input.

Comment: idk why artigos are not repeating by client only shows one , but its almost perfect!

Comment: Now you can update code as per your requirement I think! I just did logic of nested array of cliente and artigos.

Comment: i think im close to the awnswer but artigos instead of making an array with the number associated with the client is making a full object!

Comment: @Arti   You may debug that issue.

Comment: Managed to fix the issue !

Comment: Great to hear!!!

Answer (score 2):

In Javascript, you could take an array of wanted groups with

- grouping property,
- an array of properties of their grouping level,
- a wanted key name for the children of this level of grouping.

Then create a nested object (this is the same structure of every level) with a property `_` which keeps an object for the nested levels and an array of the children of the actual level.

To get a result take only the `_` property.

```js
const
    data = [{ idEncomenda: "1", codigoEncomenda: "06904", codigoArtigo: "601056", numExpedicao: "ZG0054", motorista: "Ricardo Fonseca", cliente: "Muralhas Festival", numCliente: "0067", morada: "Rua 13 de Abril", viatura: "Ferrari", matricula: "22-MM-45", rota: "Rota 01", zonaEntrega: "Aveiro Sul", dataExpedicao: "04-07-2021", observacoes: "Teste asasd agsgjsfsfd", artigo: "Sardinha Pequena EI", qtPalete: "0", caixa: "94", qtExpedida: "0", total: "120", unidade: "KG", qtPicada: "0", lote: "B211215I", dataValidadeArtigo: "16-01-2023", id: "1" }, { idEncomenda: "10", codigoEncomenda: "06945", codigoArtigo: "601056", numExpedicao: "ZG0032", motorista: "Filipe Vaz", cliente: "Viveiros Monte Real", numCliente: "0045", morada: "Rua dos Barros", viatura: "Peugeot", matricula: "65-HG-34", rota: "Rota 01", zonaEntrega: "Porto", dataExpedicao: "06-10-2021", observacoes: "asddasd", artigo: "Sardinha Pequena EI", qtPalete: "0", caixa: "54", qtExpedida: "0", total: "200", unidade: "KG", qtPicada: "0", lote: "B211215I", dataValidadeArtigo: "16-01-2023", id: "10" }, { idEncomenda: "10", codigoEncomenda: "06945", codigoArtigo: "601056", numExpedicao: "ZG0032", motorista: "Filipe Vaz", cliente: "Viveiros Monte Real", numCliente: "0045", morada: "Rua dos Barros", viatura: "Peugeot", matricula: "65-HG-34", rota: "Rota 01", zonaEntrega: "Porto", dataExpedicao: "06-10-2021", observacoes: "asddasd", artigo: "Sardinha Pequena EI", qtPalete: "0", caixa: "54", qtExpedida: "0", total: "200", unidade: "KG", qtPicada: "0", lote: "B211215I", dataValidadeArtigo: "16-01-2023", id: "10" }],
    keys = [
        ['rota', ['idEncomenda', 'numExpedicao', 'motorista', 'numCliente', 'viatura', 'matricula', 'rota', 'zonaEntrega', 'dataExpedicao','observacoes','id'], 'clientes'],
        ['cliente', ['cliente', 'numCliente', 'morada', 'codigoEncomenda'], 'artigos'],
    ],
    result = data.reduce((r, o) => {
        keys
            .reduce(function (level, [group, keys, children]) {
                let v;
                const 
                    g = o[group],
                    p = Object.fromEntries(keys.map(k => [k, (({ [k]: v, ...o } = o), v)]));

                if (!level[g]) {
                    level[g] = { _: [] };
                    level._.push({ ...p, [children]: level[g]._ });
                }
                return level[g];
            }, r)
            ._
            .push(o);
        return r;
    }, { _: [] })._;

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Holy Molly. This code is so unreadable. Should you please write some comments? For simplification. But won't change the code. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix the issue with the help of @Jaydeep Mor answer by using this:

```
    public static function getExpedicao()
{
    $expedicoes = self::find()->asArray()->all();

    foreach ($expedicoes as $idkey => $value) {
        $expedicoes[$idkey]["id"] = $value["idEncomenda"]; 
    }

    $output = [];

    $clientFields = [
        "numCliente",
        "cliente",
        "morada",
        "codigoEncomenda"
    ];

    $artigoFields = [
        "codigoArtigo",
        "artigo",
        "qtPalete",
        "caixa",
        "qtExpedida",
        "total",
        "unidade",
        "qtPicada",
        "lote",
        "dataValidadeArtigo"
    ];

    foreach ($expedicoes as $index => $data) {
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            if ($key == 'cliente' || $key == 'artigo') {
                continue;
            }

            $output[$data['rota']][$key] = $value;
        }

        foreach ($clientFields as $clientField) {
            $output[$data['rota']]['clientes'][$data['cliente']][$clientField] = $data[$clientField];
        }

        foreach ($artigoFields as $artigoField) {
            $output[$data['rota']]['clientes'][$data['cliente']]['artigos'][$data['artigo']][$artigoField] = $data[$artigoField];
        }
    }

    foreach ($output as &$item) {
        unset($item['artigo'], $item['qtPalete'], $item['caixa'], $item['qtExpedida'], $item['total'], $item['unidade'], $item['qtPicada'], $item['lote'], $item['dataValidadeArtigo'], $item['codigoArtigo'], $item['numCliente'], $item['morada'], $item['codigoEncomenda']);
    }

    // Remove rota from output array key.
    $output = array_values($output);

    // Remove cliente from output array key.
    foreach ($output as &$out) {
        $out['clientes'] = array_values($out['clientes']);
    }

    foreach ($output as &$out) {
       
        foreach ($out['clientes'] as $indexkey => &$unusedoutput) {
            $out['clientes'][$indexkey]['artigos'] = array_values($out['clientes'][$indexkey]['artigos']);
        }
    }

    return [
        "resposta" => true,
        "dados" => $output,
    ];
}
```

}